# How do i make this link change according to the name vbs pick randomly?

Tags: vbscript

```
Dim names, Rans

names = Array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12")

Rans = Int((UBound(names)+1)*Rnd())

D = names(Rans)
```

When it picks one I want it to change the url like for ex. https://website.com/user/1 or https://website.com/user/2
and I want it to navigate to that link.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.

First I would introduce a call to Randomize so that you don't get the same random number each time.

```
Dim names, Rans, oShell
names = Array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12")
Randomize
Rans = Int((UBound(names)+1)*Rnd())
D = names(Rans)

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run("https://website.com/user/" & D)
```

Using oShell.Run like this will open the URL in the default browser.

I've avoided other changes to your code, but some more meaningful variable names would make the code more easily read down the track.